# Pop up oncer per session/ visit

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, session

I want to use `jQuery` to add a pop up that appears once per session/visit.

I tried this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (!sessionStorage.previouslyVisited) {
      $('#exampleModalTextLink').modal('show');
      sessionStorage.previouslyVisited = true;
    }
  }
});
```

in this one, so that the pop up appear once per session (I made it on bootstrap 4)

```
$(window).load(function(){
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#exampleModalTextLink').modal('hide');
  }, 15000);
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#exampleModalTextLink').modal('show');
  }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set and get the session variables the following way

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    // Get saved data from sessionStorage
    var visited = sessionStorage.getItem('visited');

    setTimeout(function () {
        if (visited !== true) {
            $('#exampleModalTextLink').modal('show');
            sessionStorage.setItem('visited', true); // Save data to sessionStorage
        } 
    }, 500);

});
```

this will check for an existing value if `false` or `null` then it will call the `modal` otherwise won't, I don't know why are you using `setTimeout` if you are using the `document.ready`. See here for [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: thx a lot! it works nice and smooth! as I said I am new to javascript and jquery, I have only ktyml and css knowledege. Right now I am trying to make a site and I am gathering all pieces. I will read that documentation!
thx again!