# Show a div only when visitor see a page for the first time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I need to show a #IE only on first load of page,I dont want it on refresh ,I tried this,but it wont work for me... I explicitly need this to work with localStorage,not with session or session storage ,regarding this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5523174/8735029

HTML:

```
<p id="IE">You are not using MS browsers! Good Job!<span>x</span></p>
```

JS

```
<script>
    // detect IE8 and above, and Edge
    if (document.documentMode || /Edge/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        document.getElementById('IE').innerHTML = "You are using a MS browser,please consider using Chrome or Firefox for better experience!<span>x</span>"
    }
</script>
```

JQuery:

```
<script>


       $(document).ready(function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem('wasVisited') !== undefined) {
        $("#IE").fadeIn("slow").css("display": "flex");
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('wasVisited', 1);
        $("#IE span").click(function(){
            $("#IE").fadeOut("slow");
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Looks good. But is `localStorage` really supported by IE ?! :)

Comment: Why there's `else` in this condition? If the flag is undefined show the message and save a flag (And the above comment makes a lot of sense!)

Comment: @JonasW. I think LS has been supported since IE8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pop up oncer per session/ visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47376332/pop-up-oncer-per-session-visit)

Comment: @Alon Eitan You were right... :) so obvious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#IE").fadeOut("slow");` is inside `click` function. That's why you don't get it hidden on page refresh. Move this out and rest should work like

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
   if (localStorage.getItem('wasVisited') == undefined) {
    $("#IE").fadeIn("slow").css("display" , "flex");
    localStorage.setItem('wasVisited', 1);
   }
      $("#IE span").click(function(){
        $("#IE").fadeOut("slow");
    });
});
```

**Edit**

Change `localStorage.getItem('wasVisited') !== undefined` to `localStorage.getItem('wasVisited') == undefined`

and

`$("#IE").fadeIn("slow").css("display": "flex");` to 

 `$("#IE").fadeIn("slow").css("display" , "flex");`

Comment: I get this in my console: "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" on this line: $("#IE").fadeIn("slow").css("display": "flex");

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Change `css("display" : "flex");` to `css("display" , "flex");` and please see the updated code. Copy and paste it in your file and that should work fine this time :)

Comment: still not working...please look at the answer I provided

Comment: sorry,your answer works... thanks... I havent seen all edits you made...

Answer (score 1):

You have checked the localstorage item as !==undefined for the first time. It should be == undefined as the item will be undefined for the first time when the page opens.